# What are the correct /etc/exports settings for Kubernetes NFS Storage?

Tags: sql-server, kubernetes, nfs, kubernetes-pvc

I have a simple NFS server (followed instructions [here](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-nfs)) connected to a Kubernetes (v1.24.2) cluster as a storage class.  When a new PVC is created, it creates a PV as expected with a new directory on the NFS server.

The NFS provider was deployed as instructed [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner#with-helm).

My issue is that containers don't seem to be able to perform all the functions they expect to when interacting with the NFS server.  For example:

A PVC and PV are created with the following yml:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mssql-data
spec:
  storageClassName: nfs-client
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Gi
```

This creates a directory on the NFS server as expected.

Then this deployment is created to use the PVC:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mssql-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
     matchLabels:
       app: mssql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mssql
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      hostname: mssqlinst
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 10001
      containers:
      - name: mssql
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1433
        env:
        - name: MSSQL_PID
          value: "Developer"
        - name: ACCEPT_EULA
          value: "Y"
        - name: SA_PASSWORD
          value: "Password123"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mssqldb
          mountPath: /var/opt/mssql
      volumes:
      - name: mssqldb
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mssql-data
```

The server comes up and responds to requests but does so with the error:

> [S0002][823] com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The operating system returned error 1117(The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.) to SQL Server during a read at offset 0x0000000009a000 in file '/var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf'. Additional messages in the SQL Server error log and operating system error log may provide more detail. This is a severe system-level error condition that threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many factors; for more information, see SQL Server Books Online.

My ***/etc/exports*** file has the following contents:

```
/srv     *(rw,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

When the SQL container starts, it doesn't undergo any container restarts but the SQL service within the container appears to get into some sort of restart loop until a connection is attempted and then it throws the error and appears to stop.

Is there something I'm missing in the ***/etc/exports*** file?  I tried variations with sync, async, and insecure but can't seem to get past the SQL error.

I gather from the error that this has something to do with the container's ability to read/write from/to the disk.  Am I in the right ballpark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config that ended up working was:

`/srv     *(rw,no_root_squash,insecure,sync,no_subtree_check)`

This was after a reinstall of the cluster.  No significant changes elsewhere but still seems like there may have been more to the issue than this one config.